# Batch Script on 2008 server - If Ping successful then

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-server-2008

I am attempting to write a script that will check to see if a computer is on my LAN before running the rest of my script. It is a simple backup script using **robocopy** but  I would like it to output a file based on whether it was successful or not.
This is what I have.

```
set machine=userbox
ping -n 1 %machine% > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto BAD
goto GOOD
:GOOD
robocopy source destination
echo "backup complete" > c:\scripts\backupgood-%machine%.log
shutdown /s /m \\%machine% /t 600
goto END
:BAD
echo "Computer not on" > c:\scripts\%machine%-offline.log
:END
```

Right now the script is not detecting whether the system is on or not and it is assuming it is on and continues with the script as if the machine was able to be pinged.

Can someone point out why the error is not passing or perhaps someone has a better way of determining if a system is online.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The "problem" with your code is the management of the `errorlevel` to determine if the machine is or not online.

The questions are: how does `ping` behave?, when is `errorlevel` set?

If we are working with ipv6, the rules are

- `errorlevel` is set when there is no reply for all of the sent packets (all packets are lost)
- `errorlevel` is not set if there is a reply to any of the sent packets

ipv6 has a consistent behaviour and checking the errorlevel is a reliable way to know if the machine is online.

In ipv4 the rules are different

- `errorlevel` is set when there is no reply to at least one of the sent packets
- `errorlevel` is not set when there is a reply to all of the sent packets (no packet lost)

But pinging an non available machine on the same subnet does no set the `errorlevel`, you get an "unreachable" answer, with `n packets sent, n packed received, 0 packets lost`, all the packets get a reply from the same machine sending the packets.

This behaviour in ipv4 when the machine is in the same subnet makes the errorlevel check fail.

How to solve the problem in ipv4?

The output of the `ping` command can be checked, if the string `TTL=` is present in the output, the target machine is online.

```dos
ping -n 1 10.0.0.1 | find "TTL=" >nul 
if errorlevel 1 ( 
    echo offline 
) else (
    echo online
)
```

For a "general" solution, this (adapted from a previous answer) can be used (seems a lot of code, but almost all are comments)

```dos
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    if "%~1"=="" goto :eof

    call :isOnline "%~1"
    if not errorlevel 1 ( echo ONLINE ) else ( echo OFFLINE )

    endlocal
    exit /b

:isOnline address pingCount
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    :: send only one ping packed unless it is indicated to send more than one
    set /a "pingCount=0", "pingCount+=%~2" >nul 2>nul 
    if %pingCount% lss 1 set "pingCount=1"

    :: a temporary file is needed to capture ping output for later processing
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"

    :: ping the indicated address getting command output and errorlevel
    ping -w 1000 -n %pingCount% "%~1" > "%tempFile%"  && set "pingError=" || set "pingError=1"

    ::
    :: When pinging, the behaviours of ipv4 and ipv6 are different
    ::
    :: we get errorlevel = 1 when
    ::    ipv4 - when at least one packet is lost. When sending more than one packet
    ::           the easiest way to check for reply is search the string "TTL=" in 
    ::           the output of the command.
    ::    ipv6 - when all packet are lost.
    ::
    :: we get errorlevel = 0 when
    ::    ipv4 - all packets are received. BUT pinging a inactive host on the same  
    ::           subnet result in no packet lost. It is necessary to check for "TTL=" 
    ::           string in the output of the ping command
    ::    ipv6 - at least one packet reaches the host
    ::
    :: We can try to determine if the input address (or host name) will result in 
    :: ipv4 or ipv6 pinging, but it is easier to check the result of the command
    ::
    ::                          +--------------+-------------+
    ::                          | TTL= present |    No TTL   | 
    ::  +-----------------------+--------------+-------------+
    ::  | ipv4    errorlevel 0  |      OK      |    ERROR    |
    ::  |         errorlevel 1  |      OK      |    ERROR    | 
    ::  +-----------------------+--------------+-------------+ 
    ::  | ipv6    errorlevel 0  |              |      OK     |
    ::  |         errorlevel 1  |              |    ERROR    |
    ::  +-----------------------+----------------------------+
    ::
    :: So, if TTL= is present in output, host is online. If TTL= is not present,  
    :: errorlevel is 0 and the address is ipv6 then host is online. In the rest 
    :: of the cases host is offline.
    ::
    :: To determine the ip version, a regular expresion to match a ipv6 address is 
    :: used with findstr. As it will be only tested in the case of no errorlevel, 
    :: the ip address will be present in ping command output.

    set "exitCode=1"
    >nul 2>nul (
        find "TTL=" "%tempFile%" && ( set "exitCode=0" ) || (
            if not defined pingError (
                findstr /r /c:" [a-f0-9:][a-f0-9]*:[a-f0-9:%%]*[a-f0-9]: " "%tempFile%" && set "exitCode=0"
            )
        )
        del /q "%tempFile%"
    )

    :: cleanup and return errorlevel: 0=online , 1=offline 
    endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check for the presence of your remote directory:

```
IF EXIST "\\%machine%\Share\To\Check" (
    ECHO %machine% is available.
) ELSE (
    ECHO %machine% is not available.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you both. I tried both but in the end this is what worked for me

```
set machine=userbox
ping -n 1 %machine% | find "TTL=" >nul
IF errorlevel 1 (
echo "Computer Not On" %date% %time% > c:\scripts\%machine%-computeroff.log
) ELSE (
robocopy source destination
shutdown.exe /s /m \\%machine% /c "Mandatory Shutdown in progress. You have 10 minutes" /t 600
echo "shutdown command given" %date% %time% > c:\scripts\shutdown-%machine%.log
```

Cheers