# Q: Windows batch: script is executing both commands of an IF EXIST condition

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, command-line, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm making several batch scripts which should check if a remote PC is online before executing both commands in the script, and if it fails any of the checks to make a blank file with the "_failed" added to the log file name, which in turn triggers a failed backup notification e-mail via a *File screen* rule on the server.

The script I put together from several sources goes as follows (and is actually working pretty well so far):

```
IF EXIST "\\192.168.121.2\c$" (
robocopy "\\192.168.121.2\c$\MLINCK" "D:\Store\ProgressULJ" *.* /mir /copyall /zb /np /xf lbia*.* rcda*.* srta*.* dbi*.* *.lk /r:2 /log+:"C:\Logs\Sync-progressULJ_%DATE:~7,2%_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~12,2%.txt") else (type NUL > C:\Logs\Sync-progressULJ_%DATE:~7,2%_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~12,2%_failed.txt
)
IF EXIST "\\192.168.121.2\c$" (
7za a -tzip "D:\Daily\ProgressULJ_%DATE:~7,2%_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~12,2%.zip" "D:\Store\ProgressULJ\*" -mx=5) else (type NUL > C:\Logs\Sync-progressULJ_%DATE:~7,2%_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~12,2%_failed.txt
)
```

The issue I keep having with it is that the script creates failed logs despite the script normally going through it's actions when the host is online. When the host in question is offline, the script just dumps the empty log file and that's it, like it should. When the host is online, the script does its stuff and still makes the fail log, which triggers false alarms via email, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I tried the `if ping` version of the script (which is pretty common here) but it wasn't working as good as the `if exist` loop version, as this one kicks off immediately if the remote PC is on, but it still does a few checks if it can't connect to it immediately before skipping the command.

Comment: You have your else inside the if parenthesis, that should be outside the if.

Comment: @DennisvanGils I tried running the script by the [ss64's example](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) and some [SA advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27527499/5692016), it worked without breaking for various commands so the syntax should be sound.

Comment: DennisvanGils is right to some extent I believe. You try the script by having paranthesis in new line like: if exist "so-and-so" (  new line here. robocopy "so-and-so" new line here. ) else ( new line here. type > NUL new line here. )

Comment: @svasa Will definitely try it tomorrow with a few different iterations, thanks for the hint. Generally batch files hate breaking up commands so I tend to minimize the number of lines in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine for me.  Are you sure there's not something else going on?  Can you try to simplify it until it works and see what was breaking it? I've never used `type` to generate a file and when I did just now it gave me weird issues.  Is there a reason you're using it like you are?

```
@Echo Off
IF EXIST "\\localhost\downloads" (
    ECHO It Exists 
    ) else (    
    ECHO It does not exist, writing error
    echo test1 >> C:\temp\Sync-failed.txt
)

IF EXIST "\\localhost\fakeshare" (
    ECHO It Exists 
    ) else (    
    ECHO It does not exist, writing error
    echo test2 >> C:\temp\Sync-failed.txt
)

IF EXIST "\\fakehost\fakeshare" (
    ECHO It Exists 
    ) else (    
    ECHO It does not exist, writing error
    echo test3 >> C:\temp\Sync-failed.txt
)
```

Output:

[image]

And the contents of Sync-failed.txt:

[image]

Comment: I broke off the commands like people suggested and at least the failed state execution seems to work OK, will see next week how the script holds up during work days. Notepad++ too favors breaking off IF clauses into separate lines in batch scripts so that could possibly be it.

Comment: Checked today how the script ran compared to the others and batch indeed prefers broken lines. Who knew, thanks for your help!