# Copy .xml &.enc files from users' appdata remote machine to server location

Tags: file, vbscript, cmd, copy, xcopy

The situation is I need to grab all the .xml and .enc files from a list of remote machines' users' AppData profile folders.

I thought this might be achieved the following way:

- Ping machine to determine if it is alive.
- If not, write the result to a log file so I can keep track of failed machines.
- If the machine is alive, run a vb script or xcopy script to grab the files and copy them to the server, ideally using that user's name as the remote folder location and copying the files into there.  So perhaps `C:\Users\John.Doe\AppData\Local\Dictation\Audio\*.xml` (and `*.enc`) to `\\Server\FolderBackup\John.Doe\`.

The problem I ran into is I'm unable to get `xcopy` to copy files from a variable based location such as `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\dictation\audio` to the server so `xcopy` probably isn't the one to use.  I believe `robocopy` also suffers from this.  PowerShell may be the answer, but again I wouldn't know where to begin.

Comment: Not true. The file expansion occurs in the command terminal, not in xcopy itself. It can handle unc paths and environment variables. Maybe if you post the command you are running and the output errors we can help you further.

Comment: @FloatingKiwi

The imperfect ping script I used which outputs to Excel showing machine online status:

[Script in PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/urBneuju)

The xcopy line I used against machines which are online:
`xcopy /c /i /y /exclude:.wav \\PC\C$\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Dictation\Audio\*.xml \\Server\FolderBackup\<username>`
and
`xcopy /c /i /y /exclude:.wav \\PC\C$\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Dictation\Audio\*.enc \\Server\FolderBackup\<username>`

Comment: However, it might be as useful to use the /EXCLUDE:.wav and then do:
`xcopy /c /i /y /exclude:.wav \\PC\C$\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Dictation\Audio\*.* \\Server\FolderBackup\<username>`
But it needs to be done with a variable where the username is, so:
`xcopy /c /i /y /exclude:.wav \\PC\C$\Users\%AnyUsername%\AppData\Local\Dictation\Audio\*.* \\Server\FolderBackup\<username>`
Unless I need to GIVE xcopy the usernames, which I can do.

Comment: I thought I might be able to use something from here, but thought I'd ask the question anyway [Stack Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526490/batch-script-on-2008-server-if-ping-successful-then)

Comment: Think I may have found the problem ... but first ... your comments are a bit unreadable. When you need to post extra information to clarify something you should edit your initial post. That way your code can make the most of the formatting support provided by stackoverflow.... Now onto the issue. I was under the impression you were calling this from `cmd` which would have done the variable expansion for you. In vbscript you'll have to use `wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%\AppData" ...)`